# Hunspell returns bool instead words

Tags: hunspell

help please with Hunspell problem, can\t make this stuff works well.
Here is my code, it returns bool value TRUE unstead the suggestion of word.

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    char *aff = "c:\\en_US.aff";
    char *dic = "c:\\en_US.dic";
                Hunspell *spellObj = new Hunspell(aff,dic);
                const char *named = "hello";
                int result = spellObj->spell(named);
                char ** wlst;
                char ** wlst2;
                int ns = spellObj->suggest(&wlst,named);
                int abc = spellObj->analyze(&wlst2,named);
                 Console::WriteLine(ns);
                for (int i = 0; i<ns; i++)                  
                {

Console::WriteLine(&wlst[i]); 
                }
                spellObj->free_list(&wlst,ns);
                delete spellObj;
    Console::WriteLine(result);
    getchar();
    return 0;
```

How can i make this suggestion works?

Answer (score 0):

must use std::cout instead Console::WriteLine (facepalm)